# Stack data structure in Python using lists

Tags: python, stack, structure

For the `stack` class below

```
class stack(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []
        self.top = -1
    def isempty(self):
        return self.stack == []
    def push(self,x):
        S.top = S.top + 1
        return self.stack.append(x)

S = stack()
S.isempty() #True
S.push(5)  #[5]
S.push(100) #[5,100]
print(S) # Returns empty stack []
```

Why does it not return the updated `[5,100]`?

Comment: Why are you trying to blend inheritance _and_ composition? Choose one or the other. The reason your code printed an empty list is because you're mutating the `stack` attribute of your `stack` object, _not_ the `stack` object itself.

Comment: I have understood the mistake here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you're asking about is that you're inheriting from `list`, even though you're not trying to act like a list. All this is doing is causing confusion. In particular, you're letting the `list` superclass define how your objects get displayed, and since you never do anything like `self.append`, only `self.stack.append`, that means it's always going to display like an empty list.

Once you fix that, your objects will always print something like this:

```
<__main__.stack at 0x11d919dd8>
```

If you want to customize that, you need to write a `__repr__` method, and decide what you want it to look like.

```
class stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []
        self.top = -1
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<stack({self.stack})>'
    def isempty(self):
        return self.stack == []
    def push(self,x):
        S.top = S.top + 1
        return self.stack.append(x)
```

There are additional bugs in your code—you've still got a method that mutates the global `S` instead of `self`, and you're returning the result of `list.append`, which always returns `None`, and maybe more beyond—but these two changes will together solve the specific problem you're asking about.

Comment: As a side note: Use `'<stack({})>'.format(self.stack)` for Python 3.5 and other versions earlier than Python 3.6.

Comment: @ChristianDean Why for versions later than 3.6? f-strings aren't going away in 3.7.

Comment: Sorry, meant *earlier*.

Comment: @ChristianDean Ah, makes more sense. But I don't want the OP to actually copy and paste the code as written, I want him to decide what he wants to see when he prints out a `stack` (which is almost certainly _not_ what I'm creating), and figure out how to get that output, which is why I didn't go into any more detail on that `__repr__`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Unfortunately however, there are users out there who blindly copy 'n paste code they find. My note was for them, really.

Comment: @ChristianDean Honestly, anyone who blindly copies and pastes code without reading, and is also sticking with an old version of Python for no good reason, I feel very little obligation to help them…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6640099/christian-dean Thank you for mentioning the right format.